# a raw sql query is not working in django framework. I am getting "TypeError at / not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: django, rawsql

select *from table_name where name = %s",params={"name1","name2"}

full_code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import destination

def index(request,params = None):       
  dests1 = destination.objects.raw("select *from travello_destination where name = %s",params={'Bangalore','Mumbai'})
  return render(request,'index.html', {"dests":dests1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using raw [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) wrongly, from docs:

> params is a list or dictionary of parameters. You’ll use %s
>   placeholders in the query string for a list, or %(key)s placeholders
>   for a dictionary (where key is replaced by a dictionary key, of
>   course), regardless of your database engine. Such placeholders will be
>   replaced with parameters from the params argument.

```
  dests1 = destination.objects.raw(
   "select *from travello_destination where name = %s or name=%s", params=['Bangalore','Mumbai'])
```

Also I would advise you using [ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/) not raw queries